# regular expression in freemarker to check if first character in a string is lower case

Tags: freemarker

I am using freemarker to generate a Java class. I am stuck to convert a first character of a string to lower case.

Following is what i tryed but no luck :(

```
    <#function methodName attName > 
      <#if attName?length &gt; 1 >
        <#if  attrName(0)?matches([a-z])>
          <#return attName>
       </#if>  
      </#if>
    </#function>
```

Thanks.

Comment: IMO it's easier to do this kind of work on the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Try uncap_first:

```
${"Test"?uncap_first} yields test
```